# Sympy Piecewise and refine

Tags: sympy, simplify, piecewise

I try to simplify this `Piecewise` expression using `refine` without success. I use ***sympy*** version 1.8.

```
import sympy as sp

x,y = sp.symbols('x,y', real=True, positive=True)

expr = sp.Piecewise((1, x>=y),(0,  True))
```

expr variable contain

```
⎧1  for x ≥ y
⎨            
⎩0  otherwise
```

now I try to obtain 1 ***assuming that x>y***

```
sp.refine(expr, sp.Q.gt(x,y))
```

but I obtain the same expression

```
⎧1  for x ≥ y
⎨            
⎩0  otherwise
```

Any ideas to force this simplification ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: With sympy 1.7 you can use ```sympy.Q.is_true(x > y)```. I try ```sp.simplify(sp.refine(expr, sp.Q.is_true(x>y)))``` without success

Comment: Inequality handling is not well implemented yet in refine. This particular case you can do with `refine(expr, x >= y)`.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `expr` a value for `x` that satisfies the requirement, it will evaluate:

```
>>> eps = Symbol('eps', positive=True)
>>> expr.subs(x, y + eps).simplify()
1
```