# Analytically calculate integral of a function only under a given condition with Python-SymPy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to analytically calculate the integral of a function using this code:

```
from sympy import sqrt, symbols, integrate, pi
x=symbols('x',real=True, positive=True)
rho, r=symbols('rho r', real=True, positive=True)
f=sqrt(rho**2-(x-r)**2)
integrate(f,(x,r,r+rho)).simplify()
```

SymPy tells me the result is the one in the picture:
[image]

however I want to evaluate only the second one. How can I do that?

Comment: Presumably "the second one" refers to `sqrt(rho^2 - (r-x)^2)`, correct?

Comment: Possibly related: [SymPy -- define domain of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216750) https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html

Comment: @SuperStormer yes the one you said. I'm looking at the other post.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745502/sympy-piecewise-and-refine#comment125068994_70745502), you can pass inequalities as an assumption to [`refine`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/refine.html#sympy.assumptions.refine.refine):

```py
print(refine(integrate(f,(x,r,r+rho)).simplify(), (r - x)**2/rho**2 > 1))
# Integral(I*sqrt(r**2 - 2*r*x - rho**2 + x**2), (x, r, r + rho))
```

*(I'm not sure why this is undocumented)*

Comment: Yes it works thanks, I just had to invert the inequality. Or at least, it selects the second....tough it doesn't resolve it...ehm. SymPy doesn't seem to be very prone to give small and neat solutions. I will look into this tomorrow. I am exhausted now and off to bed.Thanks

Comment: Inequality handling is not documented because it is not well supported. In your example I think refine is basically just replacing the inequality with True in the expression just like `.subs((r - x)**2/rho**2 > 1, True)`. If the inequality in the expression were slightly different like having `>=` instead of `>` then it would probably not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what SymPy gives:

```
In [10]: i = integrate(f,(x,r,r+rho)).simplify()

In [11]: i
Out[11]: 
r + ρ                                                                                                                                                              
  ⌠                                                                                                                                                                
  ⎮   ⎧        2        2                         2                             2                            4                          2                  2       
  ⎮   ⎪     ⅈ⋅ρ ⋅(r - x)                       ⅈ⋅ρ                           ⅈ⋅ρ                    ⅈ⋅(r - x)                3⋅ⅈ⋅(r - x)            (r - x)        
  ⎮   ⎪─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── + ───────────────────────  for ──────── > 1   
  ⎮   ⎪                    3/2       ____________   ____________        __________________                       3/2        __________________          2          
  ⎮   ⎪  ⎛   2           2⎞      2⋅╲╱ -r - ρ + x ⋅╲╱ -r + ρ + x        ╱    2           2      ⎛   2           2⎞          ╱    2           2          ρ           
  ⎮   ⎨2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠                                        2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)     2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠      2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)                     dx
  ⎮   ⎪                                                                                                                                                            
  ⎮   ⎪                                                             _______________                                                                                
  ⎮   ⎪                                                            ╱  2          2                                                                                 
  ⎮   ⎪                                                          ╲╱  ρ  - (r - x)                                                                  otherwise       
  ⎮   ⎩                                                                                                                                                            
  ⌡                                                                                                                                                                
  r
```

You say that you want the second case. In general we can extract cases from a Piecewise using .args but we need to bring the Piecewise out to top lvel using `piecewise_fold` first:

```
In [12]: piecewise_fold(i)
Out[12]: 
⎧r + ρ                                                                                                                                                               
⎪  ⌠                                                                                                                                                                 
⎪  ⎮   ⎛        2        2                         2                             2                            4                          2     ⎞                2    
⎪  ⎮   ⎜     ⅈ⋅ρ ⋅(r - x)                       ⅈ⋅ρ                           ⅈ⋅ρ                    ⅈ⋅(r - x)                3⋅ⅈ⋅(r - x)      ⎟         (r - x)     
⎪  ⎮   ⎜─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── + ───────────────────────⎟ dx  for ──────── > 1
⎪  ⎮   ⎜                    3/2       ____________   ____________        __________________                       3/2        __________________⎟             2       
⎪  ⎮   ⎜  ⎛   2           2⎞      2⋅╲╱ -r - ρ + x ⋅╲╱ -r + ρ + x        ╱    2           2      ⎛   2           2⎞          ╱    2           2 ⎟            ρ        
⎪  ⎮   ⎝2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠                                        2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)     2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠      2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)  ⎠                     
⎪  ⌡                                                                                                                                                                 
⎨  r                                                                                                                                                                 
⎪                                                                                                                                                                    
⎪                                                           r + ρ                                                                                                    
⎪                                                             ⌠                                                                                                      
⎪                                                             ⎮      _______________                                                                                 
⎪                                                             ⎮     ╱  2          2                                                                                  
⎪                                                             ⎮   ╲╱  ρ  - (r - x)   dx                                                                 otherwise    
⎪                                                             ⌡                                                                                                      
⎪                                                             r                                                                                                      
⎩   

In [13]: piecewise_fold(i).args[0][0]
Out[13]: 
r + ρ                                                                                                                                             
  ⌠                                                                                                                                               
  ⎮   ⎛        2        2                         2                             2                            4                          2     ⎞   
  ⎮   ⎜     ⅈ⋅ρ ⋅(r - x)                       ⅈ⋅ρ                           ⅈ⋅ρ                    ⅈ⋅(r - x)                3⋅ⅈ⋅(r - x)      ⎟   
  ⎮   ⎜─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── - ─────────────────────── + ───────────────────────⎟ dx
  ⎮   ⎜                    3/2       ____________   ____________        __________________                       3/2        __________________⎟   
  ⎮   ⎜  ⎛   2           2⎞      2⋅╲╱ -r - ρ + x ⋅╲╱ -r + ρ + x        ╱    2           2      ⎛   2           2⎞          ╱    2           2 ⎟   
  ⎮   ⎝2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠                                        2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)     2⋅⎝- ρ  + (-r + x) ⎠      2⋅╲╱  - ρ  + (-r + x)  ⎠   
  ⌡                                                                                                                                               
  r                                                                                                                                               

In [14]: piecewise_fold(i).args[1][0]
Out[14]: 
r + ρ                      
  ⌠                        
  ⎮      _______________   
  ⎮     ╱  2          2    
  ⎮   ╲╱  ρ  - (r - x)   dx
  ⌡                        
  r
```

That seems to be what you wanted. However it is just an unevaluated integral. If that is actually what you want then you should use `Integral` rather than `integrate` in the first place:

```
In [15]: Integral(f,(x,r,r+rho))
Out[15]: 
r + ρ                       
  ⌠                         
  ⎮      ________________   
  ⎮     ╱  2           2    
  ⎮   ╲╱  ρ  - (-r + x)   dx
  ⌡                         
  r
```

The difference between `integrate` and `Integral` is that `Integral` just represents the integral symbolically whereas `integrate` will attempt to *compute* the integral ideally giving an expression that does not involve integrals:

```
In [16]: Integral(x, x)
Out[16]: 
⌠     
⎮ x dx
⌡     

In [17]: integrate(x, x)
Out[17]: 
 2
x 
──
2 

In [18]: Integral(x, x).doit()
Out[18]: 
 2
x 
──
2
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested your code and it works. However I would like to evaluate that second definite integral. Wolfram online calculator tells me it computes to the simple solution (pi*rho^2)/4. But I can't get a solution from SymPy. Any idea why?

Comment: You've changed the terms of the question quite significantly in your comment above. I did my best to respond to your original very unclear question but from here I will not respond further.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see what you are asking now. Here I am not sure why `integrate` returns the result that it does but the manual integration method will compute this integral:

```
In [3]: f.integrate((x, r, r+rho), manual=True)
Out[3]: 
            ____________________________________
   2       ╱    2                  2          2 
π⋅ρ    ρ⋅╲╱  - r  + 2⋅r⋅(r + ρ) + ρ  - (r + ρ)  
──── + ─────────────────────────────────────────
 4                         2                    

In [4]: f.integrate((x, r, r+rho), manual=True).simplify()
Out[4]: 
   2
π⋅ρ 
────
 4
```

That is using SymPy 1.11.1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate, this is exactly what I was searching for. My bad I didn't check the integrate function signature. I thought the solution to this problem lied somewhere else.